# Почему при нажатии на созданные кнопки не происходит действие (появление текста и закрашивание фона)?

Tags: java

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton [] buttons=new JButton[9];

    public Window(){
        this.setTitle("my game v 1.0");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(400,400);

        JPanel mainPnel=new JPanel();
        BorderLayout bd=new BorderLayout();
        mainPnel.setLayout(bd);
        JPanel cenralPanel=new JPanel();
        GridLayout gr=new GridLayout(3,3);
        cenralPanel.setLayout(gr);

        for (int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
            buttons[i]=new JButton();
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
            cenralPanel.add(new JButton());
        }
        mainPnel.add("Center", cenralPanel);
        setContentPane(mainPnel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
            if (buttons[i]==e.getSource()){   
                buttons[i].setText("X");
                buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
                buttons[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Банальная ошибка. Здесь:

```
cenralPanel.add(new JButton());
```

Ты создаёшь новые кнопки. А те, которым ты задаёшь Слушатели ты не назначаешь никуда. Следовательно надо заменить на:

```
cenralPanel.add(buttons[i]);
```

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: @алекстарн Пожалуйста, не забывай выделить ответ как верный, если это так.